# CiickHouse Insert unique data

Tags: python, clickhouse

I want to insert data without duplicates. Triplet of these fields should be unique `ticker, kline_type, dateTime`

Found out that i should use **ReplacingMergeTree** https://clickhouse.com/docs/ru/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree/

I am trying to

```
import clickhouse_driver

def prepare_table():
    client = clickhouse_driver.Client.from_url(f'clickhouse://default:{os.getenv("CLICK_PASSWORD")}@localhost:9000/crypto_exchange')
    
    # field names from binance API
    client.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS historical_data_binance
(
    dateTime DateTime,
    closeTime Int64,
    open Float64,
    high Float64,
    low Float64,
    close Float64,
    volume Float64,
    kline_type String,
    ticker String
) ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree
ORDER BY (ticker, kline_type, dateTime)
''')
    return client

prepare_table()
```

But I think that my solution didn't work, because I see duplicates:

```
  2021-11-04 11:00:00 │ 1636027199999 │ 61894.82 │  62188.78 │ 60866.46 │ 61444.74 │ 20.158382 │ 1h         │ BTCUSDT │
│ 2021-11-04 12:00:00 │ 1636030799999 │ 61420.86 │  61698.74 │ 58754.41 │ 61621.01 │ 15.721483 │ 1h         │ BTCUSDT │
└─────────────────────┴───────────────┴──────────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴───────────┴────────────┴─────────┘
┌────────────dateTime─┬─────closeTime─┬─────open─┬─────high─┬──────low─┬────close─┬────volume─┬─kline_type─┬─ticker──┐
│ 2021-11-04 11:00:00 │ 1636027199999 │ 61894.82 │ 62188.78 │ 60866.46 │ 61444.74 │ 20.158382 │ 1h         │ BTCUSDT
```

**What is the proper way to insert data?**

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/replacingmergetree/altinity-kb-replacingmergetree-does-not-collapse-duplicates/

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree/ Thus, ReplacingMergeTree is suitable for clearing out duplicate data in the background in order to save space, but it does not guarantee the absence of duplicates. 
Plus deduplication is eventual because it's a byproduct of merges

Comment: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/from/#select-from-final

Comment: @DennyCrane could you please elaborate your answer. Don't understand how to receive unique values

Comment: Where is the code that inserts? I suggest adding a `UNIQUE` constraint to your `CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. ReplacingMergeTree does not guarantee the absence of duplicates. You need to somehow make final deduplication on the fly in selects.
2. Deduplication is a byproduct of merges.

```sql
create table testD ( Key Int64, ver UInt64, Value String) 
Engine=ReplacingMergeTree(ver) order by Key;

insert into testD values (1, 1, '1');
insert into testD values (1, 2, '2');

SELECT * FROM testD
┌─Key─┬─ver─┬─Value─┐
│   1 │   2 │ 2     │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
┌─Key─┬─ver─┬─Value─┐
│   1 │   1 │ 1     │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘

1)
a) SELECT * FROM testD final
┌─Key─┬─ver─┬─Value─┐
│   1 │   2 │ 2     │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘

b) SELECT key, argMax(Value, ts) FROM testD group by key;
┌─Key─┬─argMax(Value, ver)─┐
│   1 │ 2                  │
└─────┴────────────────────┘

c) SELECT Key, Value FROM testD order by Key, Value desc limit 1 by Key;
┌─Key─┬─Value─┐
│   1 │ 2     │
└─────┴───────┘

2)

optimize table testD final; -- initiate unplanned merge

SELECT * FROM testD;
┌─Key─┬─ver─┬─Value─┐
│   1 │   2 │ 2     │
└─────┴─────┴───────┘
```

Comment: You can also utilize the `SELECT FINAL` syntax
 https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/from/